# Incrementating negative css value in jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am using jQuery to transform **div** with perspective:

```
function rotate ( id, value ) {
$('#' + id).stop().animate({  borderSpacing: value }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
        console.log( now );
        $(this).css({
                'transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
                '-ms-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY('+now+'deg)'
            });  
    },
    duration: 'slow'
});
}
```

Then I'm calling it with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".left").hover(
        function() {
            rotate( 'right', -60 );
        },
        function() {
            rotate( 'right', 0 );
        }
    );
    $(".right").hover(
        function() {
            rotate( 'left', 60 );
        },
        function() {
            rotate( 'left', 0 );
        }
    );
});
```

When I mouseover & mouseout the element with class right, it fluently animate the perspective rotation(it aims to the left) and returns to the default position.

On mouseover the element with class left, the animation is still fluent. However when I mouseout the element, it doesn't animate. It simply skips from -60 to 0 in one step.

> Console:

```
0
-4.258052828290663
-5.455508477249294
-6.985045445541011
-58.43305230028757
...
-59.01803258327631
-59.49764722691864
-59.81882866365539
-59.97368490296575
-60
0
0
0
...(42x 0)
0
```

As you see, the jQuery doesn't increment negative value properly. Is there a way to make this animation fluent?

Comment: But it works properly with values greater than 0. I've tried it with `stop( true, true)` and it didn't affect it. The console has shown that there is a problem with incrementing the value -60 to -59 etc. up to 0. With value 60 it decrements as expected down to 0. Also, it decrements 0 to -60 properly and increments 0 to 60. Just the first mentioned is problematic.

Comment: what are your browser considerations? maybe transitions or keyframes would be a better solution?

Comment: I've tried Chrome and Mozilla so far and it makes it like this in both browsers.

Comment: still, I'd look at css animations for this sort of thing, it's more efficient and probably the best way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the use of `border-spacing` as a placeholder value to animate, it can't be set to a negative value, so it returns zero when the value is set to a negative, making the element appear to not animate back.

You can use any other property instead

```
$('#' + id).stop(true, true).animate({
    test : value
}, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        $(this).css({
            'transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
        });
    },
    duration: 'slow'
});
```

Here's some examples

[**With border-spacing**](http://jsfiddle.net/o5x7oozd/1/)
[**Without border-spacing**](http://jsfiddle.net/o5x7oozd/)